# which has either not been installed or is abstract

Tags: django

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('mysite.apps.person.models.Person', related_name="user_journals")
```

but I am getting:

```
.. has 'user' relation with Model "mysite.apps.person.models.Person", which has either not been installed or is abstract
```

in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'mysite.apps.person',
    ...
)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you get any errors if you actually import ? Like `from mysite.apps.person.models import Person` ?

Comment: I think correct django syntax is simpler. Try with "person.Person" in the ForeignKey definition. (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)